# multidplyr with database connection

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, dplyr

I'm trying to use [multidplyr](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.md) to run a `do` command that runs a custom function that queries a Vertica database using [RJDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285503/connect-r-and-vertica-using-rodbc). I have no problem running the `multidplyr` examples or querying the database directly, but when I try to connect to the database in `multidplyr` I get the error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    3 nodes
>   produced errors; first error: No running JVM detected. Maybe .jinit()
>   would help.

I've tried the suggestion in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637181/how-to-parallelelize-do-calls-with-dplyr) to make the cluster manually, passing the `vertica` database connection object, but I still get an error that "No running JVM detected". I'm guessing that this is because I need to tell each node to start up a JVM, but I don't now how to do this.

My code, apologies that it's not reproducible as I can't share the database:

```
# set up DB connection
vertica <- dbConnect(vDriver, ...connection info...)

# create cluster
cluster3 <- create_cluster(3)
parallel::clusterExport(cl = cluster3, c("getData", "vertica"))

# run function in parallel using multidplyr
accounts_part <- multidplyr::partition(accounts, accountId, cluster = cluster3)

accounts_data <- accounts_part %>% 
  group_by(accountId) %>%
  do(getData(ac = .$accountId, vertica = vertica))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your code so my answere will be based on my experience (I had similar issue with assign (different) random number to each cluster) and on 
both [this](http://www.mattdancho.com/code-tools/2016/12/18/multidplyr.html) and [this](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.Rmd). Hope that it works.

I think your main issue is that your connection is made to link your db with the actual session and so you cannot "copy" it on each node, because they need their own "way" to the db.

On the other hand you still need to have the same name for each connection, to be able to manage them in a single (parallel) call. So, I think you have only to create the connections directly into each node instead of create one connection in the actual session and than copy it into the nodes.

```
# create cluster
cluster3 <- create_cluster(3)

# export data, function, ...
cluster_assign_value(cluster, 'getData', getData)

# setup DB connection in each cluster (evaluated in each cluster)
cluster_eval(cluster, vertica <- dbConnect(vDriver, ...connection info...))
# not
# cluster_assign_value(cluster,
#     'vertica', dbConnect(vDriver, ...connection info...)
# )
# which is evaluate locally and so it is the same as your code

# run function in parallel using multidplyr
accounts_part <- multidplyr::partition(accounts, accountId,
    cluster = cluster3
)

accounts_data <- accounts_part %>% 
    # group_by(accountId) %>% # partition() have already grouped them
    do(getData(ac = .$accountId, vertica = vertica)) # %>%
    # collect() # if you have no more computations to do and want get back
                # the results locally
```