# Multidplyr and ggmap's mutate_geocode

Tags: r, dplyr, ggmap

I am looking to geocode quickly a large number of addresses using Google's API accessed through `ggmap` (for which I am using `ggmap` version 2.7 which allows to specify a google API key through `register_google()` function).

The basic functionality works but is very slow when using `dplyr` in the following manner:

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap") #needed for v 2.7, not yet on CRAN

library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
DF %>%
  select(ID, full_address) %>%
  mutate_geocode(full_address)
```

I am getting at best 1-3 queries per second, which for a few thousand records will not be fast enough for my use. I would like to use multidplyr to run parallel queries and speed up the process.

I have seen a multidplyr [example on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712365/1731642) but I cannot seem to implement it for my case.

The solution I imagine could use `multidplyr::partition()` and either use:

1. the `ggmap::mutate_geocode()` function; or
2. the `ggmap::geocode()` function which returns a pair of columns (longitude and latitude) together with `dplyr::do()` function.

Based on the SO example linked above, I believe the code could look something like this:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggmap)
  devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")
  library(multidplyr)

  DF$split <- 1:4 # the column by which data will be split across 4 threads

  # For solution (1)
  DF %>%
  select(ID, full_address) %>%
  partition(split) %>%
  mutate_geocode(full_address)


  # For solution (2)
  DF %>%
  select(ID, full_address) %>%
  partition(split) %>%
  do(
  {ggmap::geo_code(full_address)}
     )
```

Can anyone help me get this in the correct shape? Any recommendations to make this even faster?

Comment: (1) You need to either load ggmap on the cluster, or use `ggmap::mutate_geocode`, but either way it would depend on there being a method for `party_df` (which probably isn't there). (2) Within `do` you need to refer to variables as `.$variable`, not just `variable`.

Comment: @Axeman, thanks for the quick feedback, I couldn't find a way for solution type (1) to work and I don't believe it can handle `party_df` as you had already identified. 
I did however work on (2) and it works indeed with your suggestion. I have also added a `%>% collect()` at the end to repatriate the answers from the cores. I am finding some modest speed improvements, but it seems that the Google API error rate increases equally rapidly when I ramp-up the number of parallel queries (i.e. I get NA) - not sure if this is because of the network, or some other API issue

Comment: There's probably a cap on how many API calls are allowed.

Comment: @Axeman - yes, 2,500 API calls in a day, unless you pay for extra